# Does $f_n\to f$ uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

If $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $[\delta,1]$ for all $\delta>0$ does it converge uniformly to $f$ on $]0,1]$ ?

I would say yes. We have that for all $\varepsilon>0$,$$\sup_{[\delta,1]}|f_n-f|<\varepsilon$$
if $n>N$ for a certain $N$.

But how can I get $\sup_{]0,1]}|f_n-f|<\varepsilon$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. The classic example is in a slightly different setup: $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges pointwise to zero on $[0,1)$, uniformly on $[0,1-\delta]$ for every $\delta \in (0,1)$, but it does not converge uniformly on all of $[0,1)$. If it did, then one could interchange limits and conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(1)=0$, but this limit is $1$.

You can convert this example to your setup easily enough by considering $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  As a counterexample, consider the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x}
$$